# Cannot set value of generic Property in Map

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to set the value of a property in a map but I get the following error:

```
The method setValue(capture#7-of ?) in the type WritableValue<capture#7-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#8-of ?)
```

Here is my code:

```
Map<String, Property<?>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Property<?>>();
Map<String, Property<?>> map2 = new HashMap<String, Property<?>>();

map1.put("key1", new SimpleIntegerProperty(5));
map1.put("key2", new SimpleStringProperty("hi")); //I need multiple property types in this Map, all of which implement Property

map2.put("key1", new SimpleIntegerProperty(5));
map2.put("key2", new SimpleStringProperty("hi"));

//I can assume that the value of the properties with the same key are of the same type
map2.get("key1").setValue(map1.get("key1").getValue()); //Error
map2.get("key2").setValue(map1.get("key2").getValue()); //Error
```

I cannot do this, they must be copied value only:

```
map2.put("key1", map1.get("key1"));
map2.put("key2", map1.get("key2"));
```

I can simplify this even more without the map:

```
Property<?> p1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
Property<?> p2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
p1.setValue(p2.getValue());//Same (basic) error
p1.setValue(new Object());//Same (basic) error
```

I am using Java 1.8 JDK

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: What kind of functionality are you trying to implement? Why are you mixing types? Where do the data for the map come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that what you are trying to do is inherently not type safe. You may know from the programming logic that the type of the property associated with `"key1"` in `map1` is the same as the type of the property associated with `"key1"` in `map2`, but the compiler cannot possibly guarantee that fact. So with the current structure you have, your only choice is to abandon compile-time safety.

The underlying issue here is that `Map` has the wrong API for your requirements (even though its basic functionality is what you need). `Map` is a *homogeneous* container, meaning that all the values in a given map are of the same type. This is enforced by the API: `public V get(K key);` and `public void put(K key, V value);` always use the same type `V`, which is fixed for any single `Map` instance. What you really want is a *heterogeneous* container, in which the value varies depending on the key. So you want an API in which `V` is not fixed for the instances of the container, but changes for each invocation of the methods `get` and `put`, depending on the value of the key. So you need something where the `get` and `put` methods are generic methods:

```
public interface Container<K> { // K is the type of the key...

    public <V> V get(K key) ;
    public <V> void put(K key, V value);

}
```

An implementation of this is documented in Josh Bloch's "Effective Java", and is called the "Typesafe Heterogeneous Container" pattern.

Start by defining a type for your key that maintains a type for the corresponding property:

```
    /**
     * @param <T> The type associated with this key
     * @param <K> The actual type of the key itself
     */
    public class TypedKey<T, K> {
        private final Class<T> type ;
        private final K key ;

        public TypedKey(Class<T> type, K key) {
            if (type == null || key == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("type and key must be non-null");
            }
            this.type = type ;
            this.key = key ;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == null) return false ;
            if (! (o instanceof TypedKey)) {
                return false ;
            }
            TypedKey<?, ?> other = (TypedKey<?, ?>) o ;
            return other.type.equals(type) && other.key.equals(key);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(type, key);
        }
    }
```

Here `T` will be the type of the property, and `K` is the actual type of the key. So you will modify your code to

```
// String key to map to Property<Number>:
TypedKey<Number, String> key1 = new TypedKey<>(Number.class, "key1");

// String key to map to Property<String>:
TypedKey<String, String> key2 = new TypedKey<>(String.class, "key2");
```

Now define a container class to act as the map. The basic idea here is to have two methods:

```
public <T> void put(TypedKey<T, K> key, Property<T> property)

public <T> Property<T> get(TypedKey<T, K> key)
```

The implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
    /**
     * @param <K> The type of the key in the TypedKey
     */
    public class TypedPropertyMap<K> { 
        private final Map<TypedKey<?, K>, Property<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

        public <T> void put(TypedKey<T, K> key, Property<T> property) {
            map.put(key, property);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> Property<T> get(TypedKey<T, K> key) {

            // by virtue of the API we defined, the property associated with
            // key must be a Property<T> (even though the underlying map does not know it):

            return (Property<T>) map.get(key);
        }
    }
```

There are a couple of subtleties here. Because the underlying map is `private`, we are assured the only way to access it is through our `put` and `get` methods. Thus when we call `get()` on the underlying map with a `TypedKey<T,K>`, we are assured that the corresponding property must be (`null` or) a `Property<T>` (since that is the only thing the compiler would have allowed to have been inserted earlier). So even though the compiler is not aware of it, we are guaranteed the cast succeeds, and to the `@SuppressWarnings` is justified.

Now if I create a `TypedPropertyMap<K>` (`K` here is just the type of the actual key), I am compile-time guaranteed that `map.get(key1)` returns a `Property<Number>` (because `key1` has a compile-time type of `TypedKey<Number, String>`) and `map.get(key2)` returns a `Property<String>` (because `key2` has a compile-time type of `TypedKey<String, String>`).

Here's a complete runnable example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class TypedPropertyMapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TypedPropertyMap<String> map1 = new TypedPropertyMap<>();
        TypedPropertyMap<String> map2 = new TypedPropertyMap<>();

        TypedKey<Number, String> key1 = new TypedKey<>(Number.class, "key1");
        TypedKey<String, String> key2 = new TypedKey<>(String.class, "key2");

        map1.put(key1, new SimpleIntegerProperty(5));
        map1.put(key2, new SimpleStringProperty("hi"));

        map2.put(key1, new SimpleIntegerProperty());
        map2.put(key2, new SimpleStringProperty());

        map2.get(key1).setValue(map1.get(key1).getValue());
        map2.get(key2).setValue(map1.get(key2).getValue());

        System.out.println(map2.get(key1).getValue());
        System.out.println(map2.get(key2).getValue());

    }


    /**
     * @param <T> The type associated with this key
     * @param <K> The actual type of the key itself
     */
    public static class TypedKey<T, K> {
        private final Class<T> type ;
        private final K key ;

        public TypedKey(Class<T> type, K key) {
            if (type == null || key == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("type and key must be non-null");
            }
            this.type = type ;
            this.key = key ;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == null) return false ;
            if (! (o instanceof TypedKey)) {
                return false ;
            }
            TypedKey<?, ?> other = (TypedKey<?, ?>) o ;
            return other.type.equals(type) && other.key.equals(key);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(type, key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param <K> The type of the key in the TypedKey
     */
    public static class TypedPropertyMap<K> { 
        private final Map<TypedKey<?, K>, Property<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

        public <T> void put(TypedKey<T, K> key, Property<T> property) {
            map.put(key, property);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> Property<T> get(TypedKey<T, K> key) {

            // by virtue of the API we defined, the property associated with
            // key must be a Property<T> (even though the underlying map does not know it):

            return (Property<T>) map.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it's really hard to make this an `ObservableMap`, for the same reasons outlined in the introduction: the `ObservableMap` interface defines homogeneous methods (which indeed are inherited from the `Map` interface) which you cannot implement in a way that meets your requirements. You can, however, easily make this implement `javafx.beans.Observable`, which would allow you to register `InvalidationListener`s with it, and use it in bindings:

```
   public class TypedPropertyMap<K> implements Observable { 
        private final ObservableMap<TypedKey<?, K>, Property<?>> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

        @Override
        public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
            map.addListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
            map.removeListener(listener);
        }

        // remaining code as before...
    }
```

Comment: I must also point out that I am using JavaFX's `FXCollections` to generate one of my maps, so I don't think I can make a `TypedPropertyMap`. Maybe I can still use `TypedKey<T, K>` instead of `String` when declaring the `ObservableMap<K, V>`?

Comment: I need to think about that a bit. It's pretty easy to make `TypedPropertyMap` implement `javafx.beans.Observable`, but there's no way I can see to make it implement `javafx.collections.ObservableMap`. What are your actual requirements? If it implemented `Observable` and additionally defined `addListener(MapChangeListener)` and `removeListener(MapChangeListener)` methods, but didn't implement `ObservableMap`, would that work? Even then, you might not get full type-safety on the `Change` events.

Comment: I currently have: `ObservableMap<TypedKey<?, String>, Property<?>> settings = FXCollections.observableMap(new HashMap<TypedKey<?, String>, Property<?>>());`. I don't know why I am using `FXCollections`. I don't think it is used in any views or anything. I guess I could use `TypedPropertyMap` in this case.

Comment: I guess the question is: are you attaching listeners to it, or binding to it, anywhere in the code?

Comment: Looking over my code, I guess I don't need to listen for changes in the `Map`, just the `Properties` in the `Map`. I guess `TypedPropertyMap<K>` will work fine as-is. Should `TypedPropertyMap<K>` contain an inner `Map` or extend `Map`? Would it make more sense to extend it?

Comment: It should contain a map, not extend it. The point is that `Map` is not a heterogeneous container, it is a homogeneous container (meaning that all values are the same type). This is enforced by the `Map` API: `public V get(K key);` and `public void put(K key, V value);` always use the same value type `V`. You need a heterogeneous container if you want this to be typesafe, because you want different types of properties as values. If you extend `Map` you are forced to have the `Map` API and the signatures of the `get` and `put` methods are wrong for your requirements.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you wish to continue with a type:

```
        IntegerProperty p1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
        IntegerProperty p2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
        p1.setValue(p2.getValue());
```

Or this without type safety:

```
        Property p1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
        Property p2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
        p1.setValue(p2.getValue());
```

i. e. remove the wildcard.

Comment: I need to be able to contain multiple property types in the map. Sadly, this will not work in my case.

Comment: Then Eclipse yellow underlines it and says I need a type. I know I can do @SuppressWarnings but I was hoping there is a better way, I have never had to use those, and don't want to start now.

Comment: You are working without type safety, what do you expect?

Comment: That is what I don't want to do, I want it to be type safe.

Comment: Then you need to specify a type. What type are your keys of the map, what type are the values? You can't mix integer and strings like in your example and be type safe. It's just not possible.

Comment: The general pattern for a typesafe way to keep mixed types in a container like this is called the "Heterogeneous Typesafe Container" pattern. It's a little tricky to get your head around, as it uses generics in a slightly unusual way, as "type tokens". This was first (to my knowledge) introduced in Josh Bloch's "Effective Java" (which is essential reading for all Java programmers, imho).

Comment: @James_D: I saw your code. But in the end all you did was shifting the problem from the value to the key. He'll have to determine the type of the value one way or another. May as well go with durron597's instanceof approach.

Comment: No, there's a bigger difference between the two approaches. The OP's requirement is that, given a key, only one type of `Property` can be associated with it, even in different containers. durron597's solution checks that at runtime, by testing the values stored with `instanceof`. My solution checks at *compile* time. If you write code that break the contract, in my solution it simply doesn't compile, with compile errors at the point where the violation occurs. In durron597's solution, you get an error thrown at runtime at a point in the code potentially far from the actual cause.

Comment: My point was more in direction of that he has to determine the type he wants to put into the map one way or another. Your code is undeniably superior. But for compile time safety he may as well extend from a map and use dedicated putInt/getInt, putString/getString methods. But that doesn't bind the type to the key. I don't know his use case in the end, he refuses to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JavaFX problem, this is a generics problem. Once you have the wildcard type, the `setValue` method has type `T`... which you have not specified. In other words, this is not okay:

```
Property<?> p1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
Property<?> p2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
p1.setValue(p2.getValue());
```

But this is ok:

```
Property<Number> p1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(5);
Property<Number> p2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
p1.setValue(p2.getValue());
```

You ought to be able to get around this problem by using `instanceof` checks. Ugly, but it will work.

```
Property<?> mapProperty = map2.get("key1");
if(mapProperty instanceof IntegerProperty) { 
   ((IntegerProperty) mapProperty).setValue((Integer) map1.get("key1").getValue());
} else {
   // handle the error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make `Property` an interface and have `SimpleIntegerProperty` and `SimpleStringProperty` implement `Property`. Then you would have a `HashMap<String, Property>`.

Comment: I am not sure that this would work because `Property`, `SimpleIntegerProperty`, and `SimpleStringProperty` are all built-in classes.

Comment: Oh I haven't used JavaFX before, so I didn't realize. Then either just have a `HashMap<String, Property>` and use casts or separate `HashMap`s.